# Why is the border thicker in middle?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a curved line using just CSS and HTML. For some reason the line is thicker in the middle than on the sides. Why is this happening?

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="smile"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.smile{
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Which browser, which platform?

Comment: [Replicated](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eFcVV/) in Chromium 22, Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It increases in thickness towards the middle because you have specified the `border-width` property for the bottom border of the div as `5px`. But because there are no declarations for the left or right border properties the border has to render a line from `0px` to `5px` smoothly in order to render as an appropriately rounded corner. Hence the gradual increase in thickness.